# What's the best iOS software design flow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm iOS beginner, I feel so difficult to start a project.

**What's the best iOS Software Design Flow?**

How many steps? How to write a good specification document? How to shorten design time?...

Please guide!Thank you!

Comment: steps: > 1; specification: think hard, write clear; shorten design time? > IQ

Comment: Thanks! Could you write all steps in your answer?

Comment: This is an overly broad question equivalent to "what is the best way to design software". There is no single answer and you should not expect anyone to be able to provide an actionable answer. @CaoQuy can you ask a more focused question? What problem are you trying to solve? What do you know about the problem? What do you think you need to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch Paul Hegarty's lessons on iTunes. https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255